# Can not run SSIS Package 2015 in 64 bit mode

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssis, 64-bit, sql-server-data-tools

I installed SQL Server 2017 Enterprise on Windows Server 2016 Standard. Then I installed Visual Studio 2015 enterprise edition and SSDT 2015.
Now I need to debug my SSIS package in 64 bit mode (because of the memory limitation in 32 bit mode). But when I run the package in visual studio, it always uses 32 bit version of DtsDebugHost.exe, although I have set Run64BitRuntime=true.

When I search for DtsDebugHost.exe in "Program Files (x86)" I find it in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn (this one always runs)
```

When I search for DtsDebugHost.exe in "Program Files" I only find it in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SSIS\140\Binn
```

Comment: I think your problem is SSDT 2015. SSDT 2015 only supported up to SQL Server SQl Server 2014 (maybe 2016, but pretty sure version SSDT 2016 introduced support for that). You want SSDT version 17 for SQL Server 2017. you can find SSDT 17.4 for VS 2015 here: [Previous releases of SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017). Otherwise, you'll want to install SSDT 2017 with the VS 2017 shell.

Comment: This is normal @saeed because the Visual Studios are all 32 bit apps. The 64 Bit mode is a simulation when one develops a package. Debug as usual.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. Sorry for the delay (long holidays here). But the problem seems to remain even with VS2017 and SSDT 2017. Can you check if you can run DtsDebugHost.exe by any means specially using Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks @Arthur, but I need to run it in 64 bit mode. Because my developers can not find the problem in their package without debugging in Visual Studio, and the package does not run in 32 bit mode (because of large amount of memory usage)